# How to drive a MOSFET from AC wih max efficiency?

Tags: mosfet, mains, mosfet-driver, dimmer

**Short version:** if I needed to drive a MOSFET from mains AC, that will be switching (PWMing) mains AC as well, and needed to do this "fast and often"* how should I derive the power to drive it's gate from the same mains AC?

- Fast = turning the MOSFET on or off as fast as it allows = sourcing/sinking as much current to/from gate as is it reasonable = 1+ amp per mosfet (IRF830).
- Often = PWM frequency of in the range of 20-30kHz.

**Long version:** I am making a kind of sine wave dimmer for incandescent bulbs and for this I need to drive two MOSFETs (gates and sources tied together) that will PWM-switch mains AC. Everything will be packed tightly in a closed box, so I figured that switching MOSFETs on/off as fast as possible should keep them as cool as possible. I also thought I must use gate driver because my attiny (PWM source) cannot source/sink as much current as the MOSFETs are ready to accept. The only power supply that I got is mains AC and I need to step it down to ~12V to drive the gates and provide reasonable current so I can switch them "fast and often" in 20-30 kHz.

Initially I was thinking about capacitive PSU, but all schematics that I've seen were for very low currents. I didn't take chances designing my own, as I wasn't sure if it is feasible at all (for much higher currents that is).

Then I tried it with [SR087](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/SR087), but the 100ma that it provides wasn't enough.

Now I am thinking of getting a open-PCB-type SMPS that gives me 500ma and use it to drive the gates. Something like [this, for example](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/AC-to-DC-Power-Module-Supply-Isolation-Input-AC86-265V-Output-12V-500MA-ac-adapter/1769277736.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.1.Zpr9Xt&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_7,searchweb201602_5_10017_10034_10021_507_10022_10032_10020_10009_10008_10018_10019,searchweb201603_2&btsid=9d3d73f1-076c-4b89-ac25-823860c0cc1f). What I am not sure, is can I connect it's ground to the rectified ground from mains AC. I suppose I could, as the SMPS output is floating, but I guess there's only one way to find out. Here's a rough diagram:

[image: diagram]

It does not include optoisolated UART to attiny and filters that I have yet to figure out how to design. And 1k gate resistor is not neccesary 1k, I'll try to keep is as low as possible with the final choice of gate drive PSU.

**Or is there any other way to drive MOSFETs from mains AC @10V+ and at least several hundreds of miliamps?**

Thanks a lot in advance!

**General info**: I have very basic and limited knowledge in electronics and circuit design and no formal education. I do, however, understand all the risks associated with mains AC and take it with a healthy level of paranoia.

Comment: I really can't wrap my head around your circuit diagram.

Comment: Incandescent lamps have a long thermal time constant and work quite well with 100 or 120 Hz "PWM" using triac dimmers. Can you explain your application and why you need such a high frequency? Flicker causing problems with high speed video? At those frequencies you're going to run into problems with RF emission, etc. The more info you give, the better the answers.

Comment: @transistor Perhaps he meant _florescent_ lamps.

Comment: You don't need current to keep a mosfet on (only BJTs have  that issue), you only need enough current to charge and discharge the gate capacitance so the average power needed is tiny (Fsw*Qtotal = average current or 38nC*30kHz = 1.15mA average), the mosfet symbol has no direct connection to the drain or source because it's a voltage controlled (not a current controlled) device

Comment: You really want to place that current measuring shunt between the sources of the two mosfets while grounding one end of the shunt, or your ATtiny ADC inputs will be subjected to the full wrath of mains voltage when the MOSFETs turn off.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: two mosfets have body diodes (not visible in the circuit) and thus this pair acts like a switch for AC. Attiny generates PWM (and reads current consumptions - for overload protection), gate drivers drives mosfets and SMPS generates low voltage to drive mosftets.

Comment: @Tom: I know mosfets are driven by voltage, "high" current is needed only for charging/discharging the gate for a very short time. For this reason I was pretty sure 100ma PSU (SR087) would be more than enough, but in practice in failed: the IGBT it is driving got hot really quick and the output voltage was very unstable. I thought this might me due to the fact that I used 2 x MOSFETS and at some point (when starting to turn them on) max current was >100mA. Maybe not, but the fact was that SR087 wasn't able to to drive it well.

Comment: If you want 30kHz switching, I'd opt for a 1A gate driver or so, you only need an average current of a few mA (use a few 10s of uF to supply the short bursts that the gate driver needs to dump into the fet to make it switch fast) And if you've got a dedicated gate driver, keep the gate resistance down below 10 ohms or get rid of it altogether

Comment: @transistor: thanks for the tip. My biggest problem here is not having enough problems in my life and trying to come up with some stupid ideas like "how about I make myself home automation from scratch without much knowledge in electronics?" The reason I chose to go with sine wave dimming is because I saw a challenge in that and because "in theory" they are "better". I didn't want to do TRIAC dimmers because I thought that was too easy and not interesting. I had my times of regret, and chances are, at some moment of weakness I will fallback to that solution. Maybe soon, but not yet ;)

Comment: @Tom: this is exactly what I am doing. But the SR087 does not work well in this particular setup. I implemented the exact schematic that is in it's [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SR087%20D080613.pdf), page 6.

Comment: That's pretty normal, I do things like that all the time (I often get distracted and don't finish, but anyway, it's all a learning experience)

Comment: @jms: I know and it's the way it is, just an error in schematics, my bad.

Comment: Ah, I see, this thing is a pulsed linear regulator, well that explains why it was getting so hot, I thought you were trying to PWM the light

Comment: I am trying to PWM it. I use SR0870 just to step-down 230VAC to 12VDC to have the low voltage drive the transistor, and also use it's 5V output to drive the Attiny which generates PWM and feeds in to the drivers (which uses 12V from SR087 to drive the MOSFTEs...)

Comment: @Rokas: I think the scheme is a bit nutty. You're going to go to a whole lot of trouble, create a radio jammer, try and stop it jamming radios and by the time you've finished you'll be switching to LED lighting which may not work with a high-frequency supply. You'll also have a critical part of your domestic infrastructure controlled by something only you can fix.

Comment: @transistor: there's a lot of truth in that. As I've mentioned, this scheme is rather just a "block diagram" even without some blocks, just to show the basic idea. I will put in filters and some other stuff. Maintaining such installation is another important issue and I've considered my pros/cons already. My plan B is actually to make (or take a ready-made) TRIAC dimmers and replace all bulbs with dimmable LED's. But I want to finish what I've started anyway, for the sake of learning, enjoying and maybe even having a working device. So the main question: how do I drive MOSFETS from mains AC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is somewhat conceptual with details "yet to be dealt with".

The AVERAGE gate current is much lower than the peak.
For a given Capacitance C charged to V volts the energy required is 0.5 x C x V^2. This must be charged and discharged F_PWM times per second so
Power = f/2 x C x V^2.
For C = 1 nF, C = 10V, f = 20 kHz
Power = 20,000/2 x 1E-9 x 10^2  = 1 mW mean
At 10V that's 0.1 mA mean with a CC charger or 0.2 mA mean if you "waste" half the charge energy due to the voltage ramp.

If you fed this from 300 VDC the power is VI = 300 x 0.2 mA = 60 mW.
ie if you use a zener clamped reservoir capacitor and feed it via a resistor from rectified mains peak at 300 VDC and allow suitably more than 0.2 mA

Here D1 C1 provide an ~= 300 VDC source.
R1 R2 nomunailly float C2 at half V_C! when not clamped to some other poit, but their main function is to form an effective CC (constant current) feed to C2 and to allow C2 D2 to be driven to whatever voltage is required by the driver. Z2 clamps C2 to whatever voltage is desired.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR5qAu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Somebody queried your 20 kHz PWM frequency. 
My mean current calculations assume either that this is the "PWM frame rate" with the FET being driven on or off once per frame (= effectively phase control) OR that the frame rate is much lower and that the PWM level can change at most once every 1/20 kHz = 50 uS.
IF your PWM completes a complete 256 level PWM signal in 50 uS with multiple on/off transitions in this period then a much higher gate drive current is needed and this scheme is not suitable.

In practice you can probably use a much lower frame rate